# how to make two textfield and one JCombobox have a condition just like in log-in's

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox, jtextfield

i have two textfield and one JComboboxes the problem is i want the program to check if the textfields have "admins" typed in it and administrator selected in JCombobox if so the the program will show a messagebox to the user.

Comment: Rather than just posting what you want, consider also posting the code showing what you've tried and telling us how it's not working. This way we can better understand your problem and what you may be doing wrong.

Comment: if(btn1 == y.getSource() && tf1.toString() == "admin" && tf2.toString() == "admin" && c1.getSelectedIndex() == 0 )

Answer (score 5):

Your code in your comment:

```
if (btn1 == y.getSource() && tf1.toString() == "admin" && 
        tf2.toString() == "admin" && c1.getSelectedIndex() == 0 )
```

shows you using `==` to compare Strings, and also trying to get text from a JTextField using `toString()`, neither of these is good.  Instead for String comparison, use the `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` methods, not `==` since the latter checks to see if two *objects* are identical which is not what we're generally interested. We don't care if one String is held by a different object as another but rather that the two Strings have the same chars in the same order, which is what the two equals methods do.

Next, use the `getText()` method to extract the text held by your JTextField. For example:

```
if (btn1 == y.getSource() && tf1.getText().equals("admin") && 
        tf2.getText().equals("admin") && c1.getSelectedIndex() == 0 )
```

Also, please show code as an edit to your question, not in a comment since it doesn't format well as a comment. Finally, if my advice doesn't help, consider showing us more code and giving more detailed information on the problem with this code.

Comment: i ant to post the codes that I've made but this pop up

Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: @ParodyTikTok: don't post it as an answer, but again, edit your original question and post it there.

Comment: yes! thank you my program is now working and functioning will.